# CPRA (CCPA) and LGPD admob

Tags: android, admob, privacy, privacy-policy, ccpa

After surfing the internet for a few days, I gathered the following information about the CCPA (CPRA) and LGPD. I'm currently looking for someone works with AdMob to **correct me or confirm**:

1. CPRA. We (developers) have two ways to comply with the law:

   1.1 Implement the CCPA consent form (CPRA) in the program ourself. Ask users if they are from California etc. (difficult)

   1.2. Select "Restrict data processing" in AdMob "Privacy and messaging -> CPRA -> Restrict data processing". (simple, only non-personalized ads will be shown)

[CPRA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMGS8.png)

2. There is also LGPD but we can't change any settings and the only information I found there is, that we need to add a list of ad providers to our privacy policy.

[LGPD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVPZA.png)

If there is anyone who has additional information or knows something about this, please correct me or approve. I'm a beginner solo developer and I'm having a really hard time checking all the rules I need to follow...

I found this post about CPPA: [Swift iOS -Admob how to determine if the user is a California state resident to prepare for the California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922961/swift-ios-admob-how-to-determine-if-the-user-is-a-california-state-resident-to/76249297?noredirect=1#comment134462620_76249297)

Looks like "Restrict data processing" is the safest way to comply with CPRA (CPPA).
I don't find any info about LGPD instead of Google's resources: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9930897 but there is some non-concrete info, for example: "If you believe you may be in scope of the LGPD, we recommend that you work with your legal advisors to assess whether any changes are required."

I've also tried to ask on google community AdMob help: https://support.google.com/admob/thread/215635654 , no reaction yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, @Olexiy. Brazilian LGPD is largely inspired by EU GDPR. Does your app/service have brazilian users? BR::LGPD has lots of conditions to be applied, but, in the international context, start by checking LGPD, Article 3º (next comment).

Comment: Article 3 This Law applies to any processing operation carried out by a natural person or by a legal entity governed by public or private law, regardless of the means, the country of its headquarters or the country where the data are located, provided that: I - the processing operation is carried out in the national territory; II - the purpose of the processing activity is the offer or supply of goods or services or the processing of data of individuals located in the national territory; or III – the personal data subject to the processing have been collected in the national territory.

Comment: § 1 Personal data whose holder is in the national territory at the time of collection are considered to have been collected." The original: https://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2018/lei/L13709compilado.htm